# Initializing chosen js issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

I have some code that extracts values from a list and builds a drop down select menu to use as a filter. I'm trying to get the select menu to be rendered by chosen.js but I'm having an issue get it to render properly. It appears for a split second then reverts back to the default. The code I have is as follows:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $(".chosen-select").chosen({

     no_results_text: "Oops, nothing found!",
     width: "200px"
 });

 listID = '{e14db630-4d13-4349-9153-dc3d9128ca9b}';

 var viewID = '{692ED354-A7C8-42FA-B780-CC71B5A6748D}';
 //load paramsvar
 allVars = $().SPServices.SPGetQueryString();
 var filterFieldsParams = "";
 $.each(allVars, function(objKey, objValue) {
     if (objKey.substr(0, 11).toLowerCase() == "filterfield" || objKey.substr(0, 11).toLowerCase() == "filtervalue") {
         filterFieldsParams += "&" + objKey + "=" + objValue;
     }
 });

 function getAjaxFilter(name, internalName) {
     $.ajax({
         url: $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentSite() + '/_layouts/filter.aspx?ListId=' + listID + '&FieldInternalName=' + internalName + '&ViewId=' + viewID + '&FilterOnly=1&Filter=1' + filterFieldsParams,
         success: function(data) {

             $('#filterField' + internalName).html("").append($("<div></div>").append(data).find("select"));
             $('#diidFilter' + internalName).addClass('chosen-select');



             $("select[class=chosen-select] option:first").text("Filter By Sub Category");
             $("select[class=chosen-select] option:first").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
             //clear current onChange event
             $("#diidFilter" + internalName).attr("onchange", '');
             // add change event
             $("#diidFilter" + internalName).change(function() {
                 FilterField(viewID, internalName, encodeURIComponent(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value), this.selectedIndex);
             });
         }
     });
 }

 getAjaxFilter("Sub Category", "Sub_Category");

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer - by moving the  $(".chosen-select").chosen({ part of the after the success: function(data) {

the is fixed the issue :)